# Dealing with low intra-variance and small dataset

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network, transfer-learning, siamese-network

I am trying to develop a computer vision algorithm. The goal of the system is to classify regions of interest from an image where the target classes have very little intra-variance and the background class has an enormous intra-variance (basically infinite).

Considering the low intra-variance I first looked into key-point algorithms such as SIFT and HoG. Sadly they did not work because some of the images in the target class have varying degrees of sharpness and most key points don't get detected. The logical next step would be trying to use some form of deep learning. For the target classes I have approximately 20 examples per class, so building up a model from scratch is not the way to go. I looked into using a siamese network where I keep the feature generating part completely fixed (so no gradients) and only train a dense layer which maps the flattened output of the cnn into a 128-dim representation.

I hoped that this would work and using a simple KNN classification I am able to get an almost 100% training error. However, when I test it in production the classifications are completely off and I only get the background class as prediction. My two cents would be that even though I only use the first 2 layers of a pre-trained CNN and even fix these layers the model is still heavily overfitting. I tried adding drop-out to the dense layers but again this does not seem to give satisfactory results.

Does anyone have a suggestion on where to go next? How can I make sure that the problems that I face are because of overfitting and not underfitting? I can't really use leave one out CV considering I train the siamese network on al these 20 instances.

Comment: 100% training *error*? Or accuracy?

Comment: What type of preprocessing you have made, I mean, did you crop images, for example, as it's recommended in your problem.

Comment: If you that you got 100% training accuracy. For siamese-network specially measuring trainning set accuracy is worthless as its has ability to learn the training set very well, might be considered saving it.